# How to make a Gofer load to be in the baseline of a ConfigurationOfMyProject?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, gemstone

I can successfully load this project into Pharo 5

```
  Gofer it
    url: 'http://seaside.gemtalksystems.com/ss/MockGemStone';
    configurationOf: 'MockGemStone';
    load.
  #ConfigurationOfMockGemStone asClass load.
```

But I'd like to use it as dependency on another project that has its own `ConfigurationOfMyProject` to load (which later is used by the CI in images builds).

What I've tried is to put this on the `baseline`

```
baseline11: spec
    <version: '1.1-baseline'>

spec for: #'pharo5.x' do: [
    self class ensureGitFileTree.
    spec blessing: #baseline.

    spec project: 'MockGemStone' with: [ 
        spec
            package: 'ConfigurationOfMockGemStone';
            versionString: #stable;
            repository: 'http://seaside.gemtalksystems.com/ss/MockGemStone'.
            ].
```

But that brings many validation errors like `"Error: symbolic version #stable does not resolve to a literal version. { cannotResolveVersion } [ #validatePragmas ]"`

How should I "translate" the `Gofer` load into the `spec` setup? Or where can I see documentation about how that's done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace #package: with #className:, i.e.:

```
 spec project: 'MockGemStone' with: [ 
        spec
            className: 'ConfigurationOfMockGemStone';
            versionString: #stable;
            repository: 'http://seaside.gemtalksystems.com/ss/MockGemStone'.
            ].
```